# tuple to dictionary and removing duplicate keys from Python dictionary but summing the values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below result from my python function.

```
('bread', '$1.90')
('bread', '$1.95')
('chips', '$2.54')
('milk', '$2.31')
('milk', '$2.38')
```

Now I want to make a dictionary or a list like bellow without duplicate keys but with summing values.

```
[('bread', '$3.85'), ('chips', '$2.54'), ('milk', '$7.04')]
```

My Python version is 3.5.

Comment: Your function return multiple tuples or a list of tuples or a tuple of tuples ?

Comment: Show us what you tried and didn't work for you.

Comment: My function return tuple of list like above!

Comment: I have -4 score for this question! Can I know for what? I don't know what is my fault. Please explain to me, that I can resolve my fault. Every single time, I write question here but you give me minus score and I do't really know what is my fault!? Thanks

Comment: @iSam: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​That's because: 1. You didn't post the code of your function, so we can't help you unless you post it, please [edit] your question and give us a [mcve]. 2. Your question is very simple, how about just search and try to solve the problem yourself? If you have already tried, can you please post the code you have done so far?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = [('bread', '$1.90'), ('bread', '$1.95'), ('chips', '$2.54'), ('milk', '$2.31'), ('milk', '$2.38')]
d = defaultdict(str)
for k, v in s:
    price = float(d[k][1:]) if d[k] else 0.0
    price += float(v[1:])
    d[k] = '${}'.format(price)
```

Be aware that storing the sum of the prices as strings may lead to incorrect values. A more correct approach will consist to use a class that will only sum floats (no conversion str/float) and display the result as a string.

Comment: I have this result and this is false!:
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'milk': '$0.69', 'bread': '$1.85', 'chips': '$0.54'})

Answer (score 1):

I guess not the most elegant way but:

```
tuple_out = [('bread', '$1.90'),
             ('bread', '$1.95'),
             ('chips', '$2.54'),
             ('milk', '$2.31'),
             ('milk', '$2.38')]
dic = {}
for key, val in tuple_out:
    if key in dic:
        dic[key] += float(val.replace("$",""))
    else:
        dic[key] = float(val.replace("$",""))
```

To give:

```
{'milk': 4.69, 'chips': 2.54, 'bread': 3.85}
```

Comment: Now I have this error:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
tuples = [('bread', '$1.90'),
    ('bread', '$1.95'),
    ('chips', '$2.54'),
    ('milk', '$2.31'),
    ('milk', '$2.38')]
prices = dict()

for t in tuples:
    try:
        prices[t[0]] += float(t[1][1:])
    except KeyError:
        prices[t[0]] = float(t[1][1:])
```

In the dict the price wont have the '$'

Comment: Now I have this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Do you have some regional configuration that uses ',' instead of '.' to separate decimals? Are your actual prices in the same format as your example?

Comment: No I used no separater. I have list of name and price in a .txt file. I read first line of list and after process for remove space, split and make tuples, my function give above result to me. Now I need make result like above!

Comment: I changed my function result to:
[('bread', '1.90'), ('bread', '1.95'), ('chips', '2.54'), ('milk', '2.31'), ('milk', '2.38')]

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following.

```
#encoding:UTF-8
import re

info = dict()
tuple=(('bread', '$1.90'),('bread', '$1.95'),('chips', '$2.54'),('milk', '$2.31'),('milk', '$2.38'))
for index in range(len(tuple)):
    s=re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+)', tuple[index][1])[0]
    m=tuple[index][0]
    if(info.has_key(m))
        i=info[m]+s
        info[m]=i
    else
        info[m]=s


print info
```

Comment: With this code, I have below error. For me is better, without import find a solution.
s = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+)', tuple[index][1])[0]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You are right.But I think use regular expressions is more rigorous. And I don‘t run error here.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to solve this problem:

```
#first you made a list of tuples from splitting lines as item, price
    tuple_out = [('bread', 1.90), 
                ('chips  ',  2.54), 
                ('chocolate', 20), 
                ('chocolate ', 1.95), 
                ('goods', 2.31), 
                ('insurance', 110), 
                ('loan', 195), 
                ('goods   ', 2.31),
                ('insurance', 110), 
                ('milk', 2.35),
                ('loan', 195)]

#then made a dictionary removing duplicate items with adding corresponding price to the item

    result = {}
    for k, v in tuple_out:
      result[k.strip()] = result.get(k.strip(), 0) + v
    # format dictionary as per requirement
    # here I add $ and limit up to 2 digits after decimal
    dic={}
    for k,v in result.items():
        dic[k]='${0:.2f}'.format(round(v,2))
    # convert dictionary to list and sort list
    L=([(k,v) for k, v in dic.iteritems()])
    L.sort()
    #print list of tuples
    print(L)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have this error:
result[k.strip()] = result.get(k.strip(), 0) + v
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Which version of python you used? I just tested it on python 27. It worked fine without any error. Even it worked on python 34.

Comment: I resolved it with another method. List except dictionary :)

Comment: Can you please explain me about my question minus score? I have always minus by members but I don't know for what. I need resolve this fault for future. Thanks.

Comment: for -1 score or down-vote read following links:http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228358/why-my-questions-on-stackoverflow-are-getting-downvotes-without-explanation
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer